# Preserving parts of raw content during JSON and/or XML deserialisation

Tags: java, xml, jackson, gson, fasterxml

I am looking for a mechanism to deserialise a JSON representation of a map with polymorphic values out of the following string `{"name": "your doubles", "values": [25.0, 15.0]}` and into an instance of `HashMap<String, Serializable>`. As I cannot pass individual value types to the deserialiser (even though I know them) for every element of type `Serializable` I want to keep the original JSON string representation to deserialise it into a concrete type separately. I could use fasterxml or GSON or any other library that can do the job in a sensible manner.

I would have the same question for XML serialisation.

So for the above example I would like to generate a map, which values equal `"\"your doubles\""` and `"[25.0, 15.0]"`. Effectively, I need a custom deserializer that preserves the raw data whenever it finds a node that needs to be deserialized into a `Serializable`.

There is a straightforward solution to the problem, here is using Gson:

```
Gson gson = builder
    .registerTypeAdapter(Serializable.class, new SerializableDeserializer())
    .create();

private static class SerializableDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Serializable> {
    @Override public Serializable deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return json.toString();
    }
}
```

However, if I am not mistaken this solution actually parses the node under the `Serializable` and then serialises it back. So if the value is large I will end up parsing it twice.

Additionally, I failed to implement this same solution for XML using the fasterxml XML parser. The problem there is that, as mentioned above, it actually parses the node and then serialises is back, but into JSON.

Any better JSON options?

Any XML solution?

Comment: If you know the names and types of the attributes in the JSON, why don't you deserialize it to a class, having these named and typed attributes?

Comment: This is used as a part of an RPC implementation to deserialise method arguments and then dispatch to the actual method impl. At runtime I know which method is called and which argument types it has (per reflection), but it can be any method of any service. So that structure is dynamic and there is no way to declare a type for that. Yes, I could use code generators to do that, but this is not what I want to do, I want it remain dynamic.

Comment: Then you should probably parse the whole thing as a JsonNode, as a first step, and then, once you know what each property inside the JsonNode is supposed to be mapped to, convert the JsonNode to an object of a known class.

Comment: Please suggest how as generally this is roughly what is happening in the code above: I am stopping at a JsonElement which corresponds to the data I want to preserve, but JsonElement is already parsed and that is exactly what I want to prevent.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the parsing? The problem is that you're serializing it to a string again, and then later parse the string to an object. Just store the JsonNode itself instead of its string representation, and then transform this JsonNode to an object.

Comment: Because the whole serialization logic is fully separated from the rest of the RPC invocation logic and the (de)serializer is pluggable (check https://github.com/teris-io/rpc). With your suggestion I would need callbacks and complications coupling things together. It should be fairly obvious though why I want to prevent parsing large objects twice: for throughput reasons.

Comment: A JsonNode is just a generic object representation of your JSON. Parsing to a JsonNode will just check the JSON is valid, and give you the JSON structure, as nodes. Once you have a JSON node, you can convert it to a real object, of a type you decide. This doesn't need to parse anything anymore, since the JSON has already been parsed. It only needs parsing again if, as you're doing, you transform this JsonNode into a String, and parse that String. Just don't do that.

Comment: I have just tried with `javax.json.JsonObject root = javax.json.Json.createReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)).readObject();`, which should be similar to your idea, but the resulting object is already a fully parsed entity, that is going to it with `root.get("key")` returns a _parsed_ `JsonElement` rather than raw view. So mo gain at all. I guess I will close this question, I have by now tried Gson, Jackson, javax.jason from glassfish with exactly the same result: I am not getting to slices of raw data. So be it.