# Get a dump of a section (object) of JSON

Tags: java, json, regex, jsonreader

I'm looking to dump, rather toString() a section of JSON that I want to store locally as a string, since it it is highly variable and not imperative for me to know the contents.

I'm using JsonReader for the parsing:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Unfortunately, when I reach the token that contains what I want to dump, JsonReader does not have a method for dumping the entire JSON to a string.

This is the closest that it has:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html#toString()

It seems that I may have to use regex to pull out the value of the token I am targeting.

Is there another, better solution? How would I do this with regex?

Assume that this is the sample JSON and I am targeting the `user` key:

```
{
   "id": 912345678901,
   "text": "How do I read JSON on Android?",
   "geo": null,
   "user": {
      "name": "android_newb",
      "followers_count": 41
   }
}
```

Comment: I once asked this question and got no reasonable responses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289626/preserving-parts-of-raw-content-during-json-and-or-xml-deserialisation I am still using `toString()`, which works, but then again first parsed and then converted back to string

Comment: @OlegSklyar ugh

Comment: If you find a solution, I'd be most interested to learn about it :) And yes, I tried both fasterxml ObjectMapper and Gson

Comment: I just looked into extending JsonReader but the class is `final`. Go figure.

Comment: I think I'm going to add a stringified sibling from my server of the objects I want to dump. I hate it, but I need to keep moving.

Comment: @OlegSklyar https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085100/255543

Comment: But that is exactly 1:1 my solution and it has exactly the same issue: by the time the decerializer is called JSON is already parsed (it is already a tree), which is then dumped back as JSON.